# Tokenizing f string in lexical analysis phase of Python language

Tags: parsing, lexical-analysis, f-string

I have recently learned about compilers through Aho's dragon book. As I understand it languages are first put through lexical analysis for tokenization. This process seems simple enough for languages like C/C++ and Java. But for Python, specifically Python3, how should f strings behave? I don't think lexical analysis through regex alone or using lex can tokenized string like `f"1+2 = {int(f'{1}') + int(f'{2}')}"` . I don't think regex and states can recognize that the part inside `{}` are not string characters. I have searched a bit and found this grammar for python3 using antlr https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/python/python3-py/Python3.g4 . But I don't believe it tokenizes f strings. So my question is how are f strings handled? Is it possible to handle them using lex/flex? Or are they handled in some other phase? Or do standard parser techniques not work with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's formatted string literals are designed to make the parser's job easier, at the cost of some restrictions which occasionally inconvenience users. In particular, a formatted string literal always terminates at the first occurrence of the quote which opened the literal, since it is not permitted to use that quote symbol (or sequence) anywhere in the string literal, including embedded expressions. In addition, backslashes are not allowed inside the literal, so you can't sneak in a backslash-escaped quote symbol either.

So lexical analysis is straightforward, and is not much different from any other string literal. (The main difference is the absence of backslash escapes.)

Of course, once the literal token has been identified, it will eventually be necessary to recursively parse it, at which point a lexer-state based strategy will be needed to handled embedded expressions.

Most other languages with similar features --Perl, Javascript, Posix shell and many more-- do allow arbitrary nested expressions, including expressions which include the delimiting quotes. A simple strategy for lexical analysis of such languages is to use lexical states combined with a stack of states to track recursive embeddings. This can be a bit messy, and it's certainly a deviation from the simple model outlined by Aho et al, but it's not particularly complicated.

A cleaner (in my opinion) solution would be possible by building a recursive parser/scanner, but that would require refactoring the lexical scanner in order to separate lexical analysis from input management. Neither the (f)lex nor the Antlr architectures facilitate this, although it's possible to bend them into this form.

By the way, I didn't try the Antlr parser you linked to, but it looks to me like it will tokenise formatted string literals. However, it incorrectly allows backslash escapes, so it will accept some literals which would be rejected by standard Python. I don't think it includes the code necessary to decompose the literals after they have been identified.

Comment: So, the expressions inside f strings should be parsed recursively later or lexer needs to become stack-based. Thanks, that clears it.
I actually did not know about the slash rule, so I didn't notice that in the antlr grammer.